# Spectrogram of categorical in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

Here is the dataframe I have:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'trip': [50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,53,53,53,53,
          53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,55,55,56,
         56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,58,58,58,58],
 'segment': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4],
  'class': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
          3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.head()
    trip segment class
0   50      0     3
1   51      0     3
2   51      0     3
3   51      0     3
4   51      0     3
```

So I want to plot it in a spectrogram, assigning different colours to each `class` value, say:

```
0 - black
1 - red
2 - blue
3 - green
4 - yellow
```

In this case, `trip` should act as `frequency` (y-axis), and `segment` as `time` (x-axis).

How can this be done?

Comment: your data has duplicates, how do you intent to plot them?

Comment: That's is because a `trip` may contain multiple `segments`, and `segment` is split into fixed-length instances here called `class`.

Comment: I still don't understand, I mean your data shows 4 rows with identical `trip, segment, class = 51, 0, 3`. You want segemnt on the x-axis, trip on the y-axis, but then you have 4 data points of the same class?

Comment: @QuangHoang The y-axis (`trip`) represents the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df['trip'], df['segment']))
plt.show()
```

[image]

color could not specified by `class`.
Spectrogram or heatmap's value are quantities of (x, y)

Here is `heatmap`'s value

```
segment  0  1  2  4
trip               
50       1  0  0  0
51       7  0  0  0
52       0  7  0  0
53       9  0  0  0
54       0  0  7  0
55       0  0  6  0
56       0  0  5  0
57       0  0  4  0
58       0  0  2  2
```

Another way that makes `trip` combine with `class`

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df.pivot_table(index=['trip','class'], columns='segment', values='segment', aggfunc=len))
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
segment       0    1    2    4
trip class                    
50   3      1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
51   0      1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
     3      6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
52   0      NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
     2      NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN
53   1      3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
     2      4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
     3      2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
54   0      NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
     3      NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN
55   0      NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
     3      NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
56   3      NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
     4      NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
57   3      NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
     4      NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN
58   3      NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: this is a `heatmap`, and not a `spectrogram`.

Comment: spectrogram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram

Comment: and heatmap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map

Comment: As it says: a spectrogram is usually depicted as a heat map, i.e., as an image with the intensity shown by varying the colour or brightness.

Comment: A spectrogram is frequencies vs time domain plot, and depict as heatmap, we usually call a spectrogram while the signal is processed by Fourier Transform.

Comment: From time(s) domain to frequency(Hz) domain or frequency to time domain, that's the purpose of FFT

Comment: Ref:[link](https://analyticsindiamag.com/hands-on-tutorial-on-visualizing-spectrograms-in-python/)